# gem install mysql is wrong!

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

OS:
    Fedora 13

Question:
    The mysql for rails. I inputed the command "gem install mysql" and the request is error.

Error:

    **Error:  Error installing musql:

    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb

can't find header files for ruby.

Gem files will remail installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.

Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out**

Who can help me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the ruby-devel package(s) installed

Answer (score 0):

You need to install "mysql client devel" which will install the header files and library for mysql. Then you can do "gem install mysql".